# Azure functions calling onto native C++

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm designing a new architecture in Azure. It's a multi-tenant SaaS application with an ASP.NET MVC front end and some application specific data in blob storage. I need to perform some background processing on this application data at certain points. This is currently only possible using some legacy C++ code (I can't realistically rewrite this in C#).

One thought I had was to push any background jobs onto a queue and use Azure functions to service the queue as and when a job gets pushed onto it. The sticking point is the native code. I can certainly expose methods in the native code that C# can p/invoke, but can Azure functions call onto native DLLs and if so is this a sensible approach?

Answer (score 5):

The code does run in a sandbox, but this approach should work. (you may want to consider exposing the relevant API in a managed assembly that would in turn be consumed by your function).

Whether you'll run into limitations with the sandbox is dependent on what your code is doing, but you can learn more about the sandbox and its restrictions here: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I've been having a play with WebJobs initially and although everything works locally it doesn't work when I deploy it. The problem is lack of vc++ runtime libs. Any idea how to get them into the webjob other than painstakingly including them all in the project?

Comment: I started a similar discussion here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e9f4c518-b3c8-4bbe-b9f0-2b428e25b548/can-not-load-mfc100udll-in-azure-function?forum=AzureFunctions.  I needed to use an old library that depended on an old flavor of MFC from 2010.  Though this library does seem to exist on the Azure Function VM image, it fails to load.  Other newer versions of MFC and the VC++ runtime do load and work just fine, just not mfc100u.dll.  :(  I tried manipulating paths, including the libraries with my app, and manually calling LoadLibrary(), but I could not get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

mfcu100.dll likely depends on some other DLL inside the [VC++ 2010 Redist](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555)

Most probably msvcr100.dll and msvcp100.dll.

If you include all the dependency DLLs along with your native binary, it should work.