# Azure function : Cant load DLL cognitive speech dll

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cognitive-services, azure-functions-runtime, azure-functions-core-tools, azure-function-app

> Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dll' or
>   one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Please help Been struggling for straight two weeks with this prob.

Comment: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/issues/374

Comment: Can you offer your `.csproj` file?

Comment: there is no   .csproj  i created using azure function only host.js and local.settings files

Comment: I had the same issue with a .net framework 4.8 WebAPI service. Solved it debugging on x64

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Functions doesn't support to load native functions and dynamic libraries written in C/C++. The sandbox of Azure Functions has a limitation and [The Cognitive Services Speech SDK requires the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2019 on the system.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/ship-application)

The cognitive services should be available in Azure as a resource which you can use it instead of using SDK. 
[Azure Cognitive Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/)

Comment: How do i add the service as resource

Comment: and how do I install the c++ redistributable in azure function do i use the kudu command line

Comment: @sibonisoDlamini: I think that is inappropriate and not recommend to use cognitive services SDK in azure function and it is not possible for now to install C++ Redistributable. The recommend way by Microsoft is created Azure Cognitive Services resource (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/cognitive-services-apis-create-account?tabs=multiservice%2Cwindows). Please read Microsoft official documentation.

Comment: Here is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40474314/azure-functions-calling-onto-native-c and an explanation from Azure Functions Microsoft Developer @Fabio Cavalcante that is not possible for now.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the Project Compile Settings Target CPU to x86, running the project (it fails), THEN changing the Target back to AnyCPU.

After that, no more error...